# Htaccess conditional https for static pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

My site is **HTTPS enabled** and all the pages are served using **HTTPS only**. Client now has the requirement where he wants to **show static pages like `about-us`, `termsofus` as HTTP pages and not as HTTPS**. This means that even if the user tries to open `about-us` page as HTTPS it should redirect to HTTP version of `about-us`.

My `.htaccess` code is as follows:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/about-us
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/termsofus
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/about-us [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/termsofus
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

**Problem:** Whenever I open HTTP/HTTPS version of `about-us` page it keeps on redirecting me to `index.php`.
For example: `https://example.com/about-us` to `https://example.com/index.php`

The site uses PHP YII framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI`. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it **doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules**.

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(about-us|termsofus) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(about-us|termsofus) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Can anyone explain what does this line does: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(about-us|termsofus) [NC]

Comment: That means original request doesn't start with `/about-us` and `/termsofus`

Answer (score 1):

anubhava's answer already addresses the problem and provides a good solution. I thought I'd just provide some additional explanation as to what was happening with your stated example with reference to your original code:

> For example: `https://example.com/about-us` to `https://example.com/index.php`

Given a request for `https://example.com/about-us`:

1. This matches your second rule (HTTPS is "on" and `about-us` is requested) and redirects to `http://example.com/about-us` (ie. back to HTTP).
2. The redirected request (ie. `http://example.com/about-us`) now matches the last rule and gets *internally rewritten* to `index.php` (the front-controller).
3. However, in per-directory `.htaccess` files (*directory* context) "the rewritten request is handed back to the URL parsing engine" and the process effectively starts over. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable is also updated to hold the rewritten URL ie. `/index.php`.
4. On the second pass through the `.htaccess` file the request (now rewritten to `http://example.com/index.php`) matches your first rule (HTTPS is "off" and the request is not `/about-us` or `/termsofus`) so the request is *redirected* (a second time) to `https://example.com/index.php`. (The internal rewrite is effectively *changed* into an *external redirect*.)
5. The redirected request (now `https://example.com/index.php`) does not match any rules in your `.htaccess` file, so passes through unchanged. Page is served.

If you check the network traffic, you should see the two external redirects mentioned above.

Another possible solution is to use the `END` flag (Apache 2.4+ only) on the last `RewriteRule`. This effectively *ends* the URL rewriting process, so the process stops at step #2. Although I would still favour anubhava's solution and check against `THE_REQUEST` instead, which works on Apache 2.2 and will still work should you introduce additional rewrites.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me understand what was going wrong with my code.