# .htaccess exception rules not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

These are my current rules in `.htaccess`. Basically, I want to redirect my entire site from `domain1.com` to `domain2.com` except for the following conditions:

1. all files/pages inside `/offers` folder
2. the page at `/page/company-a`

When I access `www.domain1.com/page/company-a`, I am redirected to `domain2.com/index.php` instead.

Any advice appreciated.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/offers
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page/company-a

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301]


# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
# index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: yes, i edited the question with it.

Comment: The same principle applies as to this other related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282823/htaccess-conditional-https-for-static-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI`. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(offers|page/company-a) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
# index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache while testing.

Comment: Hi! hit this when i debug it..

The debugging logs there indicate "This variable is not supported: %{THE_REQUEST}"

Comment: hi! how will i be able to find the location for the debugging logs?

Comment: Although not the cause of this recent error... there is a typo: you're missing a curly brace on the RewriteRule substitution.

Comment: Hi, may i know what "\s/+" means?

Comment: @Slay: `\s` is to ensure we match space before first `/` of URL and `/+` is to match all leading `/` in URL of `THE_REQUEST` header.  Example value of `THE_REQUEST` variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`. You should test with my latest updated full .htaccess